# How to downgrade Angular from 5 to 4 in Jhipster 4.13.3

Tags: jhipster

I am using jhipster 4.13.3. When create a gateway, it have 2 choices of Angular version: 5 or 1.x, but I want to use Angular 4.

How can I change the angular version in this version of jhipster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No easy way if you stay in 4.13.3 as some code has changed, Angular 5 was added in 4.12.0 so a workaround is to install 4.11.1: `yarn global add generator-jhipster@4.11.1`, generate your gateway and never upgrade this project.